# Wordpress Registration form automatically enable roles for an acoount with no help of an administrator

Tags: wordpress, registration

I'm sorry for my English.
I'm new here, I would like to ask. i want to create a registration form. In this registration form i would like to have a field that someone could add a code and enable a particular role for him. Also i would like to have the ability to put more than one code with a "+" button and enable more roles for this account. Is it possible to do something like this or is there any plugin to do it?

Thank you

Comment: If you mean WP roles with "roles", then you could switch roles that way, however, you can have only one role per account at a given time.

Comment: Yes I mean WP roles.thank you. only administrator can add more roles to an account?